# is there any api to clone the behavior of Android Market application? is it even possible?

Tags: java, android, google-play

Using the Android market app, or better to say, the Google Play app in your device, you can search the market and with one click you will download and install the app you want!

I'm working on a project that searches the android market for a keyword and although I can have access to the apps and their descriptions, I don't seem to be able to download the app from my app like how its done in Google Play app!

is there anyway we can do that? maybe somehow connect to the current Google Play app installed on users devices and use it for the download and the installation process?

Thanks,
Hadi

Answer (score 2):

If you know the package name of the app, you can launch an intent that will take the users to the play store via the google play app from their phone.

ex:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

If you don't want to go to google play store and use your own market-like service then you won't find an API since this is a use case google would certainly not want to entertain, since they want people to go through their store. But you can host the apk yourself on a web server and when user clicks the install button in your app, download the apk from your own web server via an API you write yourself and the default android package manager will install it for you.

Comment: Actually I don't intent to launch the Google Play app, I want to be able to somehow use an api or something from it so I can download and install an app from my own app. am I making sense?